# How can I slice an array so I am left with all elements from index 1 to the second last index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

Have a look at the function below:

```
let myFunc = (x,y)=>{
let myArray = [];
for(let i = x; i <= y; i++) {
myArray.push(i);
}
return myArray;
}
```

Assuming `x` and `y` are numbers and that `x` will always be less than `y`, the above function will return an array of all numbers between `x` and `y`. How will I be able to use array slicing method to return only the numbers from index 1 to the second last index of the array?

Comment: uhhh you could just remove the last and first elements

Comment: @IsaacVidrine what about the last, that they want gone as well?

Comment: `for(let i = x + 1; i <= y - 1; i++) {`

Comment: Did you try using Array.slice? I dont see any attempt in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code,

```js
var s = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var p = s.slice(1,s.length-1);
console.log(p);
```

Comment: `.slice(1, s.length-1)` is equivalent to `.slice(1, -1)`, by the way

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include `x` at the beginning and `y` at the end, don't include them in the loop:

```js
let myFunc = (x, y) => {
  let myArray = [];
  for (let i = x + 1; i < y; i++) {
    myArray.push(i);
  }
  return myArray;
}

console.log(myFunc(5, 25))
```

Comment: I think that was just an example of how to fill up an array.

Comment: @Barmar maybe. Bit confused why they would go through all the effort of describing the parameters if that were the case though.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a negative number as the `end` argument to `array.prototype.slice()`, and it counts from the end. So you can use `-1` to mean 2nd-to-last.

```js
let myFunc = (x, y) => {
  let myArray = [];
  for (let i = x; i <= y; i++) {
    myArray.push(i);
  }
  return myArray;
}

let anArray = myFunc(1, 10);
console.log(anArray.slice(1, -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) and [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift);

> `pop()` removes the last element of an array.
>
> `shift()` removes the first element of an array.

```js
var s = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
s.pop();
s.shift();
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
myArray = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
myArray = myArray.slice(0,myArray.length-1);
console.log(myArray)
```

[JavaScript Array Splicing](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

Comment: Edited bro. Code is out of function.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to know how to exclude the last index from the array using the slice method, sorry if the question was a bit unclear. Thanks @Keith for the illustration.